# HTML characters in detailtext

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

i'm grabbing a JSON feed with HTML characters, in the webview is displaying good. But in my TableView (detailtext) i see the HTML characters like `&#233;` what needs to be `é`. Is there a way to show `é` and not `&#233;`

```
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"description"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use that category, you will surely be of help:

[NSString+HTML](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.h)